# Copy, move and rename file causes java.io.FileNotFoundException: (No such file or directory)

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm writing several functions to copy, move and rename an uploaded file. The file is successfully copied, moved and renamed but is still throwing an error. The error is pointing to the `<cffile action=copy>`, even though the uploaded file was been copied successfully, moved to the destination 
directory and also renamed. I cannot find out what is causing this error. 
If it is relevant, my operating system is Unix and I'm using CF10.

Since I'm going to use this functionality a lot, I created several functions in a component. In my calling template (GLD_BCP.cfm) I have:

```
<CFSET destinationPath = "/home/space/users/www/DestFolder/Archive
    /#Trim(session.username)#/">
<CFSET SourcePath = "/home/space/users/www/DestFolder
    /#Trim(session.username)#">
<CFSET FileName = "#FileName#"><!--- Filename with extension --->
<CFSET MoveToPath = "/home/space/users/www/DestFolder/Archive2
    /#Trim(session.username)#/">
```

Calling functions:

```
 <CFSET FileObj = New   
 MainComp.BCP_FileData('#Trim(session.username)#','#Trim(year)#') >

 <CFSET FileObj.CopyFile('#Trim(SourcePath)#','#Trim(destinationPath)#', 
 '#Trim(FileName)#')>

 <CFSET FileObj.MoveFile('#Trim(SourcePath)#','#Trim(MoveToPath )#', 
 '#Trim(FileName)#')>

 <CFSET FileObj.RenameFile('#Trim(MoveToPath )#', '#Trim(MoveToPath )#', 
 '#Trim(FileName)#')>
```

CFC:

```
 <CFFUNCTION name="CopyFile">
        <cfargument name="SourcePath" type="String" required="TRUE">
        <cfargument name="destinationPath" type="String" required="TRUE">
        <cfargument name="FileName" type="String" required="TRUE">

        <cffile action = "copy" source = "#Trim(arguments.SourcePath)#/#Trim(arguments.FileName)#" destination = "#Trim(arguments.destinationPath)#"/>
 </CFFUNCTION>


 <CFFUNCTION name="MoveFile">
        <cfargument name="SourcePath" type="String" required="TRUE">
        <cfargument name="destinationPath" type="String" required="TRUE">
        <cfargument name="FileName" type="String" required="TRUE">
        <!--- move --->
        <cffile action = "move" source = "#Trim(arguments.SourcePath)#/#Trim(arguments.FileName)#" destination = "#Trim(arguments.destinationPath)#"/>

 </CFFUNCTION>



  <CFFUNCTION name="RenameFile">
        <cfargument name="SourcePath" type="String" required="TRUE">
        <cfargument name="destinationPath" type="String" required="TRUE">
        <cfargument name="FileName" type="String" required="TRUE">

        <cffile action = "rename" source = "#Trim(arguments.SourcePath)#/#Trim(arguments.FileName)#" destination = "#Trim(arguments.destinationPath)#/#Trim(variable.UserGroup)#_GLFeed.txt"/>
 </CFFUNCTION>
```

Error:

> ```
>  An exception occurred when performing a file operation copy on files    
>  /home/space/users/www/DestFolder/CC/TESTFILE.TXT and /home/space/users
>  /www/DsetFolder/Archive/CC/.
>
>  The cause of this exception was: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
>  /home/space/users/www/DestFolder/CC/TESTFILE.TXT (No such file or 
>  directory).
>
>  The error occurred in /home/space/users/www/webdocsec/MainComp
>  /BCP_FileData.cfc: line 25
>  Called from /home/space/users/www/webdocsec/GLD/GLD_BCP.cfm: line 32
>  Called from /home/space/users/www/webdocsec/MainComp/BCP_FileData.cfc: 
>  line 25
>  Called from /home/space/users/www/webdocsec/GLD/GLD_BCP.cfm: line 32
>
>  23 : 
>  24 :                     
>  25 : <cffile action = "copy" source = 
>   "#Trim(arguments.SourcePath)#/#Trim(arguments.FileName)#" destination 
>   = "#Trim(arguments.destinationPath)#"/>
>  26 :          </CFFUNCTION>
>  27 :
> ```

Comment: So, does `/home/space/users/www/DestFolder/CC/TESTFILE.TXT` exist, or not?

Comment: It looks like you just don't have the path correct. Don't you need a drive letter or volume name prepended? In cfInclude, if you use a relative path starting with / it's going to look in the root of the website, not the hdd. So you might be running into something like that here.

Comment: that path exist. The file that I uploaded got rename, moved and copied to the intended directory. Everything works but why this error show up at the end? should I not use / in the beginning of the path?

Comment: Time for a little troubleshooting 101 :) Add debug statements inside the various functions displaying the evaluated path values, and verifying those paths exist with File/DirectoryExists statements. That will help you spot where things go wrong.

Comment: @user3779216 Did you check with expandpath(). May be the cause of Path issue.

Comment: @user3779216 Did you call the copy() function after move the file by move() function in somewhere the page??

Answer (score 0):

I see a typo:

> An exception occurred when performing a file operation copy on files /home/space/users/www/DestFolder/CC/TESTFILE.TXT and /home/space/users/www/**DsetFolder**/Archive/CC/.

`DsetFolder` should be `DestFolder`.

Answer (score 0):

Just i've checked with your code and extra added expandPath() on all the functions destinations and source path. The file copy, move and rename functions are working fine. Its working good.

The following code which i was tried in my local,

```
<CFFUNCTION name="CopyFile">
    <cfargument name="SourcePath" type="String" required="TRUE">
    <cfargument name="destinationPath" type="String" required="TRUE">
    <cfargument name="FileName" type="String" required="TRUE">
    <!--- Copy --->
    <cffile action = "copy" source = "#expandpath(Trim(arguments.SourcePath))#/#Trim(arguments.FileName)#" destination = "#expandpath(Trim(arguments.destinationPath))#"/>
</CFFUNCTION>

<CFFUNCTION name="MoveFile">
    <cfargument name="SourcePath" type="String" required="TRUE">
    <cfargument name="destinationPath" type="String" required="TRUE">
    <cfargument name="FileName" type="String" required="TRUE">
    <!--- Move --->
    <cffile action = "move" source = "#expandpath(Trim(arguments.SourcePath))#/#Trim(arguments.FileName)#" destination = "#expandpath(Trim(arguments.destinationPath))#"/>

</CFFUNCTION>

<CFFUNCTION name="RenameFile">
    <cfargument name="SourcePath" type="String" required="TRUE">
    <cfargument name="destinationPath" type="String" required="TRUE">
    <cfargument name="FileName" type="String" required="TRUE">
    <!--- Rename Archive 2 --->
    <cffile action = "rename" source = "#expandpath(Trim(arguments.SourcePath))#/#Trim(arguments.FileName)#" destination = "#expandpath(Trim(arguments.destinationPath))#/#Trim(variable.UserGroup)#_GLFeed.txt"/>
</CFFUNCTION>
```

I tried with above my code, I am not facing any issues like as you mentioned on. Please try this and let me know if this is right solution for your problem or not.

Thanks.